# How do I get the variable with the highest Int and retrieve a String Swift

Tags: ios, swift, struct

I am building a Quiz and I have a struct with 4 Variables which are countries.

I have around 15 View Controllers with 4 buttons, each button represents one Country and increments the score by 1.

Now at the end of the Quiz, I want to display the country with the highest score and make it open a new View Controller.

```
import Foundation

var ukScore = 0
var greeceScore = 0
var italyScore = 0
var austriaScore = 0

var finalCountry = ""

struct QuizScore {
    
     func ukScoreIncrement() {
        ukScore += 1
    }
    
     func greeceScoreIncrement() {
        greeceScore += 1
    }
    
     func italyScoreIncrement() {
        italyScore += 1
    }
    
     func austriaScoreIncrement() {
        austriaScore += 1
    }
    
     func getFinalScore(){
        
        
        if ukScore == max(ukScore, greeceScore, italyScore, austriaScore) {
           finalCountry = "Uk"
        } else if greeceScore == max(ukScore, greeceScore, italyScore, austriaScore) {
            finalCountry = "greece"
        } else if italyScore == max(ukScore, greeceScore, italyScore, austriaScore) {
           finalCountry = "italy"
        } else if austriaScore == max(ukScore, greeceScore, italyScore, austriaScore) {
            finalCountry = "austria"   
        } 
    } 
}
`
```

The idea is to figure out which country wins, and then pass the string to my last class which would then prepare the next segue depending on the winning country.

Comment: My first question is why do you have 15 view controllers?, but that aside, don't use discrete variables for each "country".  Create a `Country` class or struct that has a `name` and a `score`. You can then have an array of four of these. Then determining the highest score is easy; You can sort the array by `score`, for example.

Comment: I have 15 view controllers, because we were supposed to build an app with multiple view controllers, there are some questions being answered with sliders and some being answered with switches and then some more with buttons. 

So it was easiest to create every view controller separately and then a class and pass the information through to the very last one.

Comment: Ok.  I thought it might be something like that.  I would try and work out the common question types and create reusable view controllers to pick from but that is more advanced coding.

Comment: Thats a great Tip! something I would work on when being "done" with this project - make it more efficient :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create a struct to represent each country and create an array of these. The struct would have a name and a score.

```
struct Country: Comparable {
    
    let name: String
    var score = 0
    
    mutating func incrementScore() {
        self.score += 1
    }
    
    static func < (lhs: Country, rhs: Country) -> Bool {
        return lhs.score < rhs.score
    }
}
```

Then you can create an array of these structs for whichever countries you need:

```
var countries = [Country(name:"UK"),
                 Country(name:"Greece"),
                 Country(name:"Italy"),
                 Country(name:"Austria")]
```

You can then increment scores as required

```
self.countries[0].incrementScore()
```

Your winner can then easily be found by sorting the array

```
let winner = self.countries.sorted().last()!
print("The winner is \(winner.name) with a score of \(winner.score)")
```

If you use a closure to sort the array then you can have the winner in the first element rather than the last.

To find the winner you could also iterate through the array looking for the maximum score.  My thought was that the array is fairly small, so sorting is inexpensive and sorting also gives you second place and third place etc.

Note that normally I wouldn't recommend the use of a force unwrap, but in this case you know the array isn't empty.

Using this approach you can easily create your four buttons by iterating over the array and creating a button for each element.  If you add additional `Country` instances to the `countries` array then your UI would automatically adjust.

Comment: I wouldn't sort the whole array to pick a single element. Better to use sequence's max method with a predicate.

Comment: This is so simple in a way, still teaching myself, this helped a lot! 
thank you so so much!

Comment: @LeoDabus my thought was that in a game you often want to know the ranking of all of the "players", and with a small array the sorting is fast and gives you the ranking.

Comment: @Paulw11 Sure. My comment was based on the question "I want to display the country with the highest score and make it open a new View Controller"

Answer (score 3):

Using an `enum` with a `Dictionary` seems like a better way to model this. Using the `.max()` method on `Sequence`, you can then easily determine the winner.

```swift
enum Country: Hashable {
  case uk
  case greece
  case italy
  case austria
}
```

Using `Country` as a key, we then store the score for each.

```swift
struct Quiz {
  private var scores = [Country: Int]()

  /// Add 1 to the score of the given `Country`.
  mutating func increment(_ country: Country) {
    scores[country, default: 0] += 1
  }
  
  /// Determine the winner of the quiz.
  /// - returns: The winning `Country`, or `nil` if there are no winners.
  func winner() -> Country? {
    scores.max { first, second in
      // get the maximum score, sorting each dictionary element
      // by the score (the .value of the dictionary)
      first.value < second.value
    }.map { (country, _) in
      // transform the resultant element to the "key" value
      country
    }
  }
 
}
```

You then have code completion for each possible country, and have a maintainable API.
You can then use a `switch` on the result to trigger a segue (or any other code).

```swift
var q = Quiz()

q.increment(.uk)
q.increment(.austria)
q.increment(.austria)
let winner = q.winner() // "austria"

switch winner {
case .uk:
  triggerUKSegue()
case .greece:
  triggerGreeceSegue()
case .italy:
  triggerItalySegue()
case .austria:
  triggerAustriaSegue()
case nil:
  print("no winner yet!")
}
```

This is just an example, it may be wise to just have a single "result" view, and pass it the winning `Country` to display some result.
Additionally, we're not checking if there is more than 1 winner at the moment.

Comment: First of all, Thanks a lot for your efforts and helping! 

Depending on the button that is clicked, I increment with q.increment(.uk) 
On the last View Controller I added a "Result" button with the switch to determine the winner, but it always shows "no winner yet" 
even though I clearly only go for one winner.